# Why is the javascript replace throwing an error

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax-error

I keep getting this error "SyntaxError: syntax error" at the first comma, what should I change to make it work?

```
if (location.pathname.replace(/^//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname)
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting suggests something is not right, see that? Double-check your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slash in your regex

```
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the double slashes,

```
if (location.pathname.replace(/^/,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^/,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname)
```

Comment: I think op intended the "/" to be there, only needed to be escaped. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RegExp` constructor

```
var regexp = new RegExp("^/", "");
if (location.pathname.replace(regexp,'') == this.pathname.replace(regexp,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname)
```

or escape character `/`

```
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname)
```